# Calling functions from a C++ dylib and Header in a Cocoa Application

Tags: cocoa, dylib

Great website, has been super helpful these past few weeks.
I am writing an app in Cocoa that requires the use of a C++ dylib and header files.
I need to call functions from a header file in my app.
Ive tried several ways to import and include these libraries into my app but always end up with missing symbol errors.
The libraries i am using are from the autodesk maya API, anyone have any idea the correct way to do this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the files calling the functions are Objective-C++ files (basically, give them the extension ".mm"), and you need to add the library to your project so it gets linked in.

Comment: I am new to mac. How do you reference library in xcode ? dylib is dynamic library do you not do some kind of loadlibrary in code and call functions via pointer ? or can it be referenced like a static library in project ?